# NLTK internals.py error

Tags: python, tagging, nltk

I've been trying to setup hunpos on my windows system but am experiencing some issues.

The error i get is

```
File "C:\Users\a\Desktop\x.py", line 25, in <module>
ht = HunposTagger('english.model')
File "C:\Python27-32\lib\site-packages\nltk-2.0.1rc4-py2.7-win32.egg\nltk\tag\hunpos.py", line 84, in __init__
verbose=verbose)
File "C:\Python27-32\lib\site-packages\nltk-2.0.1rc4-py2.7-win32.egg\nltk\internals.py", line 526, in find_binary
url, verbose)
 File "C:\Python27-32\lib\site-packages\nltk-2.0.1rc4-py2.7-win32.egg\nltk\internals.py", line 510, in find_file
raise LookupError('\n\n%s\n%s\n%s' % (div, msg, div))
LookupError:   ===========================================================================
NLTK was unable to find the hunpos-tag file!
Use software specific configuration paramaters or set the HUNPOS environment variable.

Searched in:
- C:\Users\a\
- .
- /usr/bin
- /usr/local/bin
- /opt/local/bin
- /Applications/bin
- C:\Users\a/bin
- C:\Users\a/Applications/bin
```

I'm guessing there's a bug in nltk's internals.py but not sure how to fix it. I added os.getcwd() to hunpos_paths in hunpos.py but it doesn't help.

Does anyone know why this is happening?

Thanks

Comment: That's a pretty nice error message. What is this HUNPOS env var of which they speak? Have you set that?

Comment: it's in hunpos.py 
    `self._hunpos_bin = find_binary(...env_vars=('HUNPOS', 'HUNPOS_HOME'), searchpath=hunpos_paths...)`
I set `HUNPOS` in my env var as well.

Comment: i actually changed internals.py to print the `filename` and not `name` as described here `https://github.com/nltk/nltk/issues/217`

Comment: `>>> config_hunpos-tag('C:\Users\a\')
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
NameError: name 'config_hunpos_tag' is not defined`

Answer (score 0):

Do you have the file `english.model`? If you do, set the environment variable `HUNPOS` to the directory that contains it, and run python again. If you still get an error, check that the directory appears in the list of locations searched.

Comment: If it's not searching in the directory you gave it, it's not yet seeing HUNPOS. Check for yourself by printing `os.environ['HUNPOS']` from the interpreter prompt (after `import os`)

Comment: Is the error saying it searched the directory in question? If yes, there's only one more thing I can think of (I don't have hunpos): Try setting HUNPOS to the full name of the model, including the filename.

Comment: the error says it's unable to find the hunpos-tag file (which is an executable for win platforms). i tried setting it to the tag file and then the model file but neither worked

Comment: Read the whole error, it tells you which directories it searched in.

Comment: yes, i know. i've tried everything suggested here and more but don't know why i still have the error.

Comment: So does it search in the directory specified by HUNPOS, or doesn't it?

Answer (score 0):

Did you compile hunpos-tag on your own? If not, and you downloaded the binary from google code or any other place, it cannot be the case that the runnable is actually an exe file (I have no idea whether exe extension is needed by windows for a file to be executable or not), and hunpos.py calls `find_binary()` to locate `hunpos-tag`, but not `hunpos-tag.exe`? I don't know how `find_binary()` works, but this may be the problem.

Answer (score 0):

```
from nltk.tag.hunpos import HunposTagger
ht = HunposTagger('english.model', 'hunpos-1.0-win/hunpos-tag.exe')
ht.tag('What is the airspeed of an unladen swallow ?'.split())
ht.close()
```

You need to set hunpos files paths as arguments.